# How to inform the View about the Command's success

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a small database app following the MVVM pattern. In order to modify the database I use dialogs (the view) and then call commmands that are definined in the view's view model. But how do I tell the view about the success/result of this command?

A simple example: the user wants to delete a row but there are still remaining relations so the row can't be deleted. In my opinion and understanding of MVVM it's the view's job to notice the failure and also the view's job to inform the user about the problem. I think it would be wrong to create this special view directly from the view model after the operation failed. I thought about events to solve this problem (like the mediator pattern I use for view model communication). But these events should also allow to pass parameters. In this example the paremter should be a string containing all remaining relations so the user also understands why the operation failed.

Has someone a suggestion to solve this problem? I would very much appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the row should be in a collection that is bound. The view should simply send a command to the viewmodel that says "delete this row", and its interests should stop there. The viewmodel should be responsible for actually deleting the row and removing it from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. Use errors collection (`ObservableCollection`) in view model class. Bind any items control in your view to this collection. When command faulted, add an error to the errors collection.

Option 2. When command faulted, show a message box with error message to user. To follow MVVM, show it via service or post a message to any mediator-like type.

Both of options (either adding new error in collection, or message box) must be implemented in the view model, not in the view.